# Why is this Javascript setTimeout and setInterval running into a race condition?

Tags: javascript, carousel, settimeout, setinterval, race-condition

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
 window.setInterval(rotateCarousel, 5000);
});

function fadeCarousel(n, e, t, s){
 var carousel = window.setInterval(function(){
  console.log(t/s);
   if (e.children[n].style.opacity>0){
    e.children[n].style.opacity = String(parseFloat(e.children[n].style.opacity) - .01);
   }
   
   if (e.children[(n+1) % e.childElementCount].style.opacity <1){
    e.children[(n+1) % e.childElementCount].style.opacity = String(parseFloat(e.children[(n+1) % e.childElementCount].style.opacity) + .01);
   }
 }, t/s);
 
 window.setTimeout(function(){
  clearInterval(carousel);
 },t);
};

function rotateCarousel(){
 var carouselinner = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-inner")[0];
 var activeChild = 0;
 
 for (i=0; i< carouselinner.childElementCount; i++){
  if (carouselinner.children[i].classList.contains("active")){
   activeChild=i;
   i=carouselinner.childElementCount;
  }
 }
 
 fadeCarousel(activeChild, carouselinner, 500, 100);
 carouselinner.children[activeChild].classList.remove("active");
 carouselinner.children[(activeChild+1) % carouselinner.childElementCount].classList.add("active");
};
```

```css
.carousel { 
  z-index: -100; 
} /* keeps this behind all content */

.carousel .item {
 top:0;
 left:0;
  position: fixed; 
  width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;
 background-position: center;
}

.carousel .one {
  background-color:green;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 .carousel .two {
  background-color:blue;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 .carousel .three {
  background-color:yellow;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 .carousel .four {
  background-color: red;
  background-size: cover;
 }
```

```html
<div id="BackgroundCarousel" class="carousel container slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item one active" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
    <div class="item two" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
    <div class="item three" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
    <div class="item four" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above is an example of what I'm running into.

What I'm wanting to do is have a background's transparency rotate in and out on a set interval, so I use `setInterval` to call a function `rotateCarousel` that marks a `div` as the displayed div and calls the transition.

In changing, I want to have a fade transition, so I have a function `fadeCarousel` that will adjust the opacity of the two adjacent background divs on a short interval.  Since I want the fading of the divs to stop, I clear the fading `setInterval` in a `setTimeout` with a delay that should allow for everything in `setInterval` complete.

It seems when I use exact values for the delay on clearing the interval that the browser doesn't have enough time to for the `setInterval` fading to complete and when the `setTimeout` runs the `clearInterval`, sometimes the `setInterval` for the fade is not complete.  This leaves me with a background looking stuck in transition.

I've tried to work around this by giving around 5x the delay as should be needed for the `clearInterval` to be called but it still seems to have an issue sometimes (without the large margin, it seems to have the race condition everytime).  I also have the `console.log` print out `t/s` because in Firefox it seemed that without this `t` & `s` would get optimized away and weird stuff was happening.

What I am I not understanding about `setInterval` and `setTimeout` - why is there a race condition here?

Comment: Javascript only can do one thing at a time (aka: single-threaded). Use CSS and transitions instead to control the opacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your for loop was wrong when you change active element you interval not completed. that why when next element active then you interval has cleared. and your race condition. I have fix this code, I'm try to call set interval next element after clear forward element interval. see code snipped

```js
var activeChild = -1;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
 rotateCarousel();
});

function fadeCarousel(n, e, t, s){
 var carousel = window.setInterval(function(){
    console.log(t/s);
   if (e.children[n].style.opacity>0){
    e.children[n].style.opacity = String(parseFloat(e.children[n].style.opacity) - .01);
   }
   
   if (e.children[(n+1) % e.childElementCount].style.opacity <1){
    e.children[(n+1) % e.childElementCount].style.opacity = String(parseFloat(e.children[(n+1) % e.childElementCount].style.opacity) + .01);
   }
 }, t/s);
 window.setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("clear");
  clearInterval(carousel);
    rotateCarousel();
 },t); 
};

function rotateCarousel(){
  activeChild+=1;
 var carouselinner = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-inner")[0];
  if(carouselinner.childElementCount <= activeChild){
    activeChild = 0;
  }
   console.log("element: " + activeChild); 
  if(activeChild > 0){
     carouselinner.children[activeChild - 1].classList.remove("active");
  }
 carouselinner.children[activeChild].classList.add("active");
  fadeCarousel(activeChild, carouselinner, 3000, 1000);
  
};
```

```css
.carousel { 
  z-index: -100; 
} /* keeps this behind all content */

.carousel .item {
 top:0;
 left:0;
  position: fixed; 
  width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;
 background-position: center;
}

.carousel .one {
  background-color:green;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 .carousel .two {
  background-color:blue;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 .carousel .three {
  background-color:yellow;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 .carousel .four {
  background-color: red;
  background-size: cover;
 }
```

```html
<div id="BackgroundCarousel" class="carousel container slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item one" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
    <div class="item two active" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
    <div class="item three" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
    <div class="item four" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your code set interval to call **rotateCarousel()** that when your function **fadeCarousel** called, then Interval of **rotateCarousel** called :) that make **fadeCarousel** call faster than intervall insite **fadeCarousel** function. EX:

1: window.setInterval(rotateCarousel, 5000);// **A** mean after 5s rotateCarousel will call.

2: fadeCarousel(activeChild, carouselinner, 500, 100); //**B** after 500ms close.

but: when **A** make next call means after 5s **B** has been completed 4.5s before. Think: after **A** make a call **B** has been completed 5000 - (n * 500ms) that why **activeChild** race condition (I'm working for improving my Eng) if you not understand please tell me make a example.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this and figuring out what is wrong.  I don't understand why what I did caused this race.  Was the for loop still executing when the setInterval was executing?  I don't understand why or how this would happen.  Shouldn't rotateCarousel have always been called after the for loop was done?  Thanks again for your insight, having it work is great but I'd love to understand the issue.

Comment: ok, thanks, so what I don't understand is where the "n" in "after A make a call B has been completed 5000 - (n * 500ms)" comes from.  Why is it "5000 - (n * 500ms)" and not always "5000 - (1 * 500ms)"?  I realize that B is called multiple times (once for each interval of A), but since within every interval of A, B has a shorter period, shouldn't B always finish before the next A is called?  If B always finishes first, shouldn't n=1, always?  How does B keep getting delayed so that B feels like A is called sooner (and hence B does not complete before the next A)?  Thanks again for helping!